# How do I use kubectl via an ssh tunnel to access my internal ELB over my kubernetes API?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, ssh-tunnel, kops

I want to create a kubernetes cluster using KOPS that uses a private topology completely (all master/worker nodes are on private subnets, the API ELB is internal).

Once the cluster is created - how do I configure kubectl to use an ssh tunnel via my bastion server ?

Comment: I also want to set up this configuration, using a private subnet would be better. Did you happen to figure it out in the end?

Answer (score 8):

I found a way to make `kubectl` to run through an SSH tunnel, it's not ideal, but until I find something better, I posted it now.

First create the tunnel:

```
ssh -f user@XX.XX.XXX.XX -L 6443:localhost:6443 -N
```

Then copy the `~/.kube/config` file on your local machine and change the cluster `server` in order to point to 127.0.0.1 instead of the server URL or IP address.

As the certificates are made for the server where the master node has been created, you'll get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.0.0.1, not 127.0.0.1
```

You have to pass the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify=true` flag:

```
kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:44:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.1", GitCommit:"4485c6f18cee9a5d3c3b4e523bd27972b1b53892", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-18T09:09:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I hope this helps, and I hope to find a better way to avoid this `--insecure-skip-tls-verify=true` flag.

---

## Update

Since my comment, I found the [Teleport](https://gravitational.com/teleport/) project from [Gravitational](https://gravitational.com), which was initially an SSH tool to authenticate without passwords (you login once, with an [OTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password), and a certificate with a validity limited in time for your user is delivered and used to authenticated to the allowed servers.), is also Kubernetes compatible.

Basically you have to :

1. deploy their binary and configure it (quite easy).
2. login using `tsh login --proxy https://yourserveripaddress:3080`
3. use `kubectl` to access your cluster.

The magic thing here is that Teleport will update your `~/.kube/config` file in order to access your cluster.

It really works well and you should consider giving it a try.

In the case you're using [Chef](https://www.chef.io), I have made [a cookbook for Teleport](https://gitlab.com/pharmony/teleport-ce-cookbook/).

Comment: you can specify the `insecure-skip-tls-verify: true` option under the `cluster` settings in the `~/.kube/config`

Comment: When creating a cluster  (for example with kubeadm), you can include '127.0.0.1' in your api server SAN. Then you won't need to provide `insecure-skip-tls-verify: true` when tunneling the kubectl client requests into your cluster. There are also ways to update the api server's SAN on a running cluster but it requires some extra work depending on how the cluster was initially created.

Comment: See @Eduardo Pinheiro answer below, it is the documented approach for SSH tunnels using SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use VPN over SSH what will be transparent for your kubectl, example tool: https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle which create VPN tunnel using SSH and iptables

Requirement is to have at least python 2.3 on bastion host.

Comment: Adding yet another service on the box doesn't answer the question.

Comment: But it's an alternative to disabling cert verification... not sure why you would downvote tbh

Comment: Either way this was exactly what I was looking for, and using https://github.com/kayrus/kuttle was able to do it over kubectl .. PERFECTO! Thanks!

Comment: See @Eduardo Pinheiro answer below, it is the documented approach for SSH tunnels using SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you can use [SOCKS5 proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/socks5-proxy-access-api/) .

##### On your client machine creates a socks proxy

*this is establishing an SSH connection to the specified server and creating a dynamic port forwarding tunnel. You can create it in any available port.*

```bash
# on your client machine
ssh -D 8002 -q -N username@your-bastion-server.example.com

# on another terminal on your client machine run
HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://localhost:8002 kubectl get pods

# ----- or ------
export HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://localhost:8002
kubectl get pods
```

You can also add it to your ~/.kube/config

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LRMEMMW2 # shortened for readability 
    server: https://<API_KUBE_CLUSTER_IP_ADRESS>:443  # the "Kubernetes API" server, in other words the IP address of kubernetes cluster api ip and port
    proxy-url: socks5://localhost:8002   # the "SSH SOCKS5 proxy" in the diagram above
```

Check the initial link for more information...

Comment: Just adding an additional note that this is considered stable since K8S v1.24, the docs say: "Before kubectl 1.24, most kubectl commands worked when using a socks proxy, except `kubectl exec`".